# Rademacher Complexity of the family of constant-valued functions

Tags: machine-learning, computational-statistics

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a **family of constant-valued functions** with values in the closed interval $[a, b]$，how to calculate the rademacher complexity of $\mathcal{H}$?

We know that the definition of rademacher complexity is
$$
\mathfrak{R}_m(\mathcal{H})=\frac1m \mathbb{E}_{\boldsymbol \sigma,S}\left[
\sup_{h\in\mathcal{H}} \sum_{i=1}^m \sigma_ih(x_i)
\right]
$$

To calculate $\mathfrak{R}_m(\mathcal{H})$, should we consider the values of $a$ and $b$? I feel that there are many situations for this question, and I have not made any progress at the moment. Could you help me solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help!